# Getting the "Large Text" font size from Settings/Accessibility?

Tags: iphone, uifont

The Settings/Accessibility "Large Text" setting sets the text size in some built-in Apps.

How can I get hold of this setting to be used in my own App? I can create a private setting in my App of course, but I'd rather use the global setting.

I was expecting `[UIFont systemFontSize]` to adjust the size, but it always returns 14 regardless of the setting in Accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. I opened [rdar://10660048](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1764407) just in case, hopefully something similar will be available in iOS 6.x. If somebody knows private APIs to access the value I wouldn't mind *knowing*.