# Matching Accessibility Large Text font size

Tags: ios, xcode, accessibility

I have request from a client to match the "Large Text" font size set in the Accessibility section of the Settings app.

[I found a post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606209/use-large-text-accessibility-feature-in-ios-app) But it doesn't actually gives an answer.

[I also found this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305273/getting-the-large-text-font-size-from-settings-accessibility) : but its from last year.

Is there an API to access this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did a quick search and they essentially said what your first link said. You need to be certified (or whatever) by Apple to gain access

Answer (score 1):

In iOS7 you get that for free with TextKit, and on UIApplication there's a property called preferredContentSizeCategory to access this value directly.